# How do PANs and Hosts interact?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun, sr5-matrix

What will happen to your PAN when you use the **Enter Host** action?
I have always assumed that your PAN goes with you, but in [this](http://forums.dumpshock.com/lofiversion/index.php/t39456.html) thread it was suggested that only your persona goes in.

> Mind you the whole Persona overrides the Device setup doesn't mean his entire PAN Icon goes with him, only the device that he is using to hop onto the matrix with (his deck, commlink, or RCC) is converted into the persona. In other words, you can't slave everything to a commlink and then open an AR window and travel into a secure host to prevent someone from hacking your gun, or cyberware. This trick only works for your commlink, deck, RCC, etc. It also may impose a -2 distraction penalty to your real world actions because of the matrix overlay in your senses.

If there is no RAW ruling, what are the consequences of house ruling either way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct, only your persona comes with you.

Now, let me throw down the why's.

An icon is defined on Pg. 217 of RAW 1st Ed as:

> Everything in the Matrix is an icon, a virtual representation that allows you to interact with something in the Matrix. ... Everything in the Matrix is an icon, a virtual representation that allows you to interact with something in the Matrix.

A person is defined on Pg. 218 of RAW 1st Ed as:

> A persona is the combination of a user and a device that gets the user onto the Matrix.

And a PAN is defined on Pg. 219 of RAW 1st Ed as:

> Most individuals have multiple electronic devices on them at once, and having icons for each one show up would provide too much visual clutter in the Matrix. Often, what shows up instead is an icon representing an individual’s personal area network.

Keep in mind, when dealing with Shadowrun usually the answer to grabbed easily from real life.

The first explanation is the simplest: You are identified by your persona, which is how you want to look like. People don't see the device, just the fact that something is there, just like if you pinged a computer. The only reason people can tell I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 7 is my User Agent: If I changed that (my persona) to install tell them I'm a fat, ugly troll, that's all they would see.

Looking over those definitions, the Persona offers the simplest answer: following the definition on Pg. 218, you can see

> Persona icons usually look like the people they represent (although who can resist making a nip here, a tuck there, a facelift, and maybe some nicer hair?), sometimes with a splash of style like flashing eyes, hair coloring, or a tastefully understated aura.

Therefore, nobody sees anything about you aside from your persona, until Other Things start happening.

What if they come upon your meat body, though? Even while your persona is off that the nova-hot club trying to make a deal, anyone with AR or VR will be able to see your PAN, because they are nearby. Unless you're running silent, of course, in which case they'd have to make a check, but that's beside the point.

**Addendum**

You pointed out in the comments that it says the following on Pg. 246 of RAW 1st Ed:

> Once you're inside, you can see and interact with icons inside the host, but not outside (with the same caveat for messages, calls, etc.).

This wording is a bit tricky. Before this, it says:

> When you're outside of a host, you can’t interact directly with icons inside it, **although you can still send messages, make commcalls, and that sort of thing**.

The bolded part is the caveat of the sentence, which is referenced here:

> Once you're inside, you can see and interact with icons inside the host, but not outside **(with the same caveat for messages, calls, etc.)**.

The book, in a roundabout way, explains that you can send messages, commcalls, and etcs to icons whether they are inside a host or not, but you can't otherwise directly interact with them (aka hack).

Comment: My main problem with this is that according to p.246 _Once you’re inside, you can see and interact with icons inside the host, but not outside (with the same caveat for messages, calls, etc.)._ so how would you access your PAN and the files on your commlink if they stay outside of the host?

Comment: I will get to that this evening!

Comment: @Korusef - Hopefully the edit explains it better.